# Nodejs promise not working when using q library

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I am trying to learn promises on my own. This is the code I wrote -

```
var Q = require('q');

var promise = Q.fcall(function() {
  // I expect this time out to delay returning the response 7.
  setTimeout( console.log('hi'), 1000 );
  return 7;
});

promise.then(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents);
});
// Added this timeout so that the javascript execution context(node ex.js) remains alive before the code in the then block is resolved.
setTimeout( function(){console.log('bye');}, 1000 );
```

Now this is not printing the contents. I just get 
C:\node\Ex_Files_UaR_Node\first>node example3.js
hi
bye

I was expecting to get -
hi
7
bye

Please let me know if there is anything very much evident which I am missing.

EDIT:

P.S The below code resolves the promise -

```
var Q = require('q');

var promise = Q.fcall(function() {
  setTimeout( function(){console.log('hi');}, 1000 );
  return 7;
});

promise.then(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents);
});

setTimeout( function(){console.log('bye');}, 1000 );
```

However the basic idea behind adding setTimeOut in Q.fcall was to delay the execution of the promise. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: That's wrong on just so many levels. When exactly did you expect the `setTimeout`s to run?

Comment: I added setTimeOut to add some delay so that it takes some time before promise gets resolved. But since it was not getting resolved, I thought may be the execution itself is over before the promise is resolved and thats why I am not getting the response. Thats why I added the second timeout at the end so that it buys some time for the promise to resolve.

Comment: So between which of the logs do you expect it to wait a second?

Comment: Added comments in the question before the setTimeout calls. hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Forget about Q, use ES6 Promises it's more clear.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not going to block your code, it will just run the code when the timeout expires in a different context. Also you're not using it properly, the first argument should be a function to execute, here you are passing it whatever the result of `console.log` is. [Read about setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Ok. I get that setTimeOut will not block. But then my promise should get resolved , right ?
console.log(contents);
I don't see the contents getting printed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your 1st log statement.

I've modified your code to work properly.

```
var Q=require('q');
var promise = Q.fcall(function() {
    setTimeout( function(){console.log('hi')}, 1000 );
    return 7;
})
promise.then(function(contents) {
    console.log(contents);
});

setTimeout(function(){console.log('bye');}, 1000 );
```

But this code will print 7 , bye and hi in respective order because, the following actions happens syncronously:

- Promise gets registered with the call to the function `fcall()` .
- The promise variable registers a handler using `then()` method.
- Your timeout function, which is aiming at logging 'bye', is registered.

Now the following things happens asynchronously in the following order:

- Your registered promise callback, where you are registering a timeout
  function to print 'hi' and returning value 7, is called as callback
  from `fcall()`.
- Now the setTimeout registers the function aiming to log 'hi' and
  returns value 7.
- Promise gets resolved with value 7 and it logs the value to console.
- The timeout for 'bye' gets expired and logs it to the console.
- The timeout for 'hi' gets expired and logs it to the console.

Hope it makes the flow clear.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. Actually the basic intent to add setTimeOut was to delay the promise from returning 7 immediately. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: I found a way to delay the execution of promise -

var Q = require('q');

var deferred = Q.defer();

var promise = Q.fcall(function() {
  setTimeout( function(){console.log('hi');deferred.resolve(9);}, 1000 );
  return deferred.promise;
});


promise.then(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents);
});

setTimeout( function(){console.log('bye');}, 1000 );

Comment: Since this was not the original ask of the question, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
   setTimeout(() => resolve(4), 2000);
});

p.then((res) => {  
  console.log(res);
});
```

ES6 Promises are simpler. p is resolved only after 2 seconds. Till then, It is not resolved, neither rejected. So then executes only after 2 seconds

Comment: ya. Promise will resolve immediately above. Actually I wanted to add some delay so that I can test the asynchronous nature of promises. Any idea how can that be done ?

Comment: not necessarily. However I had used $q before in an angular js based application. That's why I have done this way.

Comment: I can do that with ES6 Promises. Can I answer again?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the problem of not getting the 7 in the output (even though your code has several logical mistakes), as this snippet (without any of the corrections) *does* produce it:

```js
// This is browser version, so `require` is replaced by `script src` tag.
//var Q = require('q');

var promise = Q.fcall(function() {
  // I expect this time out to delay returning the response 7.
  setTimeout( console.log('hi'), 1000 );
  return 7;
});

promise.then(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents);
});
// Added this timeout so that the javascript execution context(node ex.js) remains alive before the code in the then block is resolved.
setTimeout( function(){console.log('bye');}, 1000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.5.0/q.js"></script>
```

There are however several issues:

- The first argument to the first `setTimeout` is not a function: you pass it `console.log('hi')` instead of `function(){console.log('hi');}`.
- `return 7` will be executed immediately. If you want a delay for the initial promise to settle, then `Q.fcall` is not the method you need: you need `Q.Promise` instead.

Here is how your *intended* behaviour would be coded then:

```js
var promise = Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        console.log('hi');
        resolve(7);
    }, 1000 );
});

promise.then(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents);
});

setTimeout( function(){console.log('bye');}, 1000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.5.0/q.js"></script>
```

Note that Node has a native Promise library with which you can do the same. There is really no need to include Q. Just replace `Q.Promise(...)` with `new Promise(...)`:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        console.log('hi');
        resolve(7);
    }, 1000 );
});

promise.then(function(contents) {
  console.log(contents);
});

setTimeout( function(){console.log('bye');}, 1000 );
```

Note that there is a slight difference in the output order for the "7". This is because the native implementation of Promises uses a microtask to schedule the execution of the `then` callback, while `Q` uses an event on the main queue to schedule that execution, which comes later. Many will consider the native behaviour "more correct".